# Joining three tables (link table)

Tags: sql, join

Need help with a query that I wrote:

I have three tables

**Company**

```
id     name
1      Gary's
```

**Employee**

```
id     name         company_id
1      Tim Jones       1
2      Sam Adams       1
```

**reports to**

```
employee_id      reports_to_id
     1                 2
```

My current query is:

```
select 
   temp.company.name as comp_name, 
   temp.employee.name as employee_name, 
   temp.employee.id as employee_id 
from temp.employee, temp.employee
where temp.company.id = temp.employee.company_id and temp.company.id = 1
```

Which gives me the output of:

```
comp_name    employee_name     employee_id
 Gary's       Tim Jones           1
```

I need something like this:

```
comp_name     employee_name    reports_to
Gary's         Tim Jones        Sam Adams
```

What's a good way to modify my query to do this? I have a query and then I take those results and run a second query against that result set (which is excessively unnecessary).

Comment: Could you, please, go into more details about `temp.contact` table?

Comment: Your query and output don't match. What table is `contact_name` coming from; is that supposed to be `employee_name`? Also, what table is the `reports_to` coming from? Is that supposed to be another employee.name? Is `Sam Adams` employee ID `1032012`?

Comment: `from temp.employee, temp.employee` is correct?

Comment: I've modified the original question. I've added table example and fixed up concerns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming an employee only reports to one person then we could have (no link table)

```
Employee  (Id, Name, CompanyId, ReportsToId)
Company (Id, Name)
```

Then you could have a query similar to

```
select e.Name EmployeeName, c.Name CompanyName, r.Name ReportsTo
from
    Employee e
        inner join Company c on e.CompanyId = c.Id
        inner join Employee r on e.ReportsToId = r.Id
where
    e.CompanyId = 1
```

If the employee reports to multiple people then we would use a link table

```
Employee  (Id, Name, CompanyId)
EmployeeReportsTo (EmployeeId, ManagerId)
Company (Id, Name)

select e.Name EmployeeName, c.Name CompanyName, r.Name ReportsTo
from
    Employee e
        inner join Company c on e.CompanyId = c.Id
        inner join EmployeeReportsTo ert on ert.EmployeeId = e.Id
        inner join Employee r on ert.ManagerId = r.Id
where
    e.CompanyId = 1
```

Comment: I had that written out but I was waiting for disambiguation.